# AS3 - Removing a button and re adding it

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

Sounds like a strange question I know.

```
removeChild();
addChild();
```

the problem occurs when I remove the button, the button has been exported for actionscript, when I remove the button to change the page/page layout, when I return to the page, the button remains in its "over" state.

so im wondering if there is a way to reset it either before its removed or when its added.

I cannot use `gotoAndStop(1);`
because I am working in a package file.

Comment: Would it be possible to merely hide the button until it's needed again?

Comment: potentially, but that will use memory, I don't like having objects off stage.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about resetting when the object is added or removed from the stage:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, function(ev:Event):void
{
    trace('Added');
});

addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, function(ev:Event):void
{
    trace('Removed');
});
```

You can reset the state in either of these functions, but I don't see any reason to avoid doing it explicitly, e.g. `object.reset()`.

Comment: hmm, Im not sure that helps, its cool that you can listen to those events, but I am trying to force the button back to its normal state, so that when I add it to the stage, it doesnt look like someones already hovering over it, as the buttons get removed from the page, then on return they are white, stuck in the over state.

This is for an iOS application, but im guessing that doesnt matter.

object.reset():
didnt work, obviously I change the object to library_btn or library as its an imported class library:library_btn=new library_btn;

Thanks for any additional help :)

Thor110

Comment: OK, so your question is "How do I change the state of the SimpleButton class?"  Apparently you can't.  Just switching to `visible` is the easiest way to fix this.  There isn't a difference in memory usage unless you're using `cacheAsBitmapMatrix` and you are referring to the GPU memory (since you're targeting iOS).